# Give IDs to all the EditTexts that come after pressing the "add" button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Following the code given in the sample app [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html), I created an activity which can add EditTexts on the screen. I would like to know how to assign them IDs so that I can extract the text entered or already present in them.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ViewGroup mContainerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContainerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
            // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add_item:
            // Hide the "empty" view since there is now at least one item in the list.
            findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addItem();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void addItem() {
    // Instantiate a new "row" view.
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_example, mContainerView, false);

    // Set the text in the new row to a random country.
    ((EditText) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            COUNTRIES[(int) (Math.random() * COUNTRIES.length)]);

    // Set a click listener for the "X" button in the row that will remove the row.
    newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the row from its parent (the container view).
            // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
            // this removal is automatically animated.
            mContainerView.removeView(newView);

            // If there are no rows remaining, show the empty view.
            if (mContainerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
    // adding this view is automatically animated.
    mContainerView.addView(newView, mContainerView.getChildCount());
}

/**
 * A static list of country names.
 */
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain",
        "Austria", "Russia", "Poland", "Croatia", "Greece",
        "Ukraine",
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign IDs to the Views, they are generated automatically in android.R. To retrieve them use `findViewById(R.resource)`

```
final EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resource);
String myText = edit.getText.tostring();
```

Comment: But using that how would i use EditText's getText() method to get the text present in a particular EditText among other EditTexts?